# How to sort an object array by browsing by week?

Tags: javascript

I would like to sort and modify the output of an object array by browsing week by week from the earliest date, to sort by week the sum of qt.

```
Datas: [
{qt: 3, date: 03-03-2020},
{qt: 2, date: 02-14-2020},
{qt: 4, date: 13-03-2020},
{qt: 3, date: 04-02-2020},
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
week1: 3,
week2: 6,
week3: 0,
week4: 0,
week5: 3
]
```

I’ve been trying to turn it all up since yesterday, but I'm starting to have a lot of trouble. I'm working on React with Akita. If you have possible algorithm orientations, I am interested.

Comment: There is only one `tag` you need to add on, `javascript`, which is currently not

Comment: `[week1: 3, week2: 6, ...]` is not a valid syntax. Do you mean `{week1: 3, week2: 6, ...}`?

Comment: Depending on your date format either `02-14-2020` or `13-03-2020` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy).

```
var _ = require('lodash');
const ordered = _.orderBy(Datas, 'date', 'asc');
```

it sort your Datas according to date by ascending.I realize that you want erroneous form as desired result you cannot make it `[week1: 3]` it should be `[{week1:3}]` but it doesn't matter. You should make a list [3,6,0,0,3] and assume that their indexes represent their week number.So following code gives you the list:

```
const desiredResult = ordered.map(obj => {
    return obj.qt;
});
```

Also you may want visit [this website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) to learn how to install lodash

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is above all to travel PER WEEK in a date range (the oldest to that of today). It is a question of isolating even in the first emps to obtain:

```
[{
week1: {qt: ..., date: ...}, //week1 = date range between Monday and Sunday
week2: {qt: ..., date: ...},
...]
```